# Inject environment variables in playwright-ct config?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, playwright, playwright-test

I have been using playwright component testing experimental feature ( Experimental: components ) I want to inject environment variables in playwright-ct.config.ts, so that they are accessible in test environment.

This is how config file looks like.

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/experimental-ct-react';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config({ path: '/env/.env.test', override: true });

export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './playwright/component',
  snapshotDir: './playwright/__snapshots__',
  timeout: 10 * 1000,
  fullyParallel: true,
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  reporter: 'html',
  use: {
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
    baseURL: 'https://localhost',
    ctPort: 3100,
    ctViteConfig: {
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@utils': resolve(__dirname, '../ui/src/utils'),
          '@type': resolve(__dirname, '../types'),
          '@constants': resolve(__dirname, '../ui/src/constants'),
          '@hooks': resolve(__dirname, '../ui/src/hooks'),
          '@ui/type': resolve(__dirname, '../ui/src/types')
        }
      },
      envDir: "/env/.env.test",
      define: {
        "process.env": process
      }
    }
  },
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] }
    }
  ]
});
```

As per the config file, I have tried some approaches as seen above to have environment variables in testing environment but unfortunately it doesn’t seem to work.

I have a component that I want to test, inside that component I am using a hook useAnalytics() that internally uses env.variables however when I run my test I get the err about missing URL as the URL comes from process.env if I hardcode the URL it works so somehow I believe my testing environment don’t have access to environment variables.

I have already tried adding below snippet as well.

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({ path: '/env/.env.test', override: true });
```

Here is how my test case look like.

```
export const Analytics = () => {
  const { shareClickEvent } = useAnalytics();

  return (
    <>
      <p>Testing hook</p>

      <button onClick={() => shareClickEvent(AnalyticsPageType.PDP)}>Share Click Analytics</button>

    </>
  );
};
```

Here is the hook

```
const useAnalytics = () => {
      const analytics = useAnalytics(process.env.ANALYTICS_URL);
   .......
}
```

when I run the test I get this err.

Error: url must be passed with first call of hook.

I am running my test case using  `yarn run test-ct --headed`